# Can't drop any element on cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a menu builder like that of WordPress where each menu item (`<li>` element) is sortable and dropable so that a user is able to drag and drop any menu item onto any other menu item and build a nested menu of any depth. 
I am able to drag and drop a cloned menu item but my problem is that I am unable to drop any element on the cloned elements.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".main-menu, .sub-menu-1, .sub-menu-2").sortable({  

    connectWith: '.menu-group',
    placeholder: 'drop-placeholder'

  }).disableSelection();



//The problem occurs regarding the HTML below. I clone the `<li>` 
//element and I append it to a `<ul>` element where all `<li>` 
//elements are sortable and dropable. However I am unable to drop 
//any element on cloned elements.


  $('.btn-add-menu-item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $(".menu-checkbox").each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('ui-sortable-handle');
        $(this).next('ul').addClass('sub-menu-1 menu-group ui-sortable');
        $(this).parents('li').clone(true).appendTo('.main-menu');
      }


    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.drop-placeholder{
   border: 1px dashed green;
}

.menu-group{
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<!-- Below is the HTML of new menu items to clone -->
<!-- and add when the button is clicked -->


<ul class = "add-menu">
 <li> 
  <input type = "checkbox" class = "menu-checkbox">New Menu Item 1
  
  <ul class = "new-menu">
   <!-- Here is empty must be dropable to receive <li> elements -->
  </ul>
 
 </li>
 
 
 <li> 
  <input type = "checkbox" class = "menu-checkbox">New Menu Item 2
  
  <ul class = "new-menu">
   <!-- Here is empty must be dropable to receive <li> elements -->
  </ul>
 
 </li>



</ul>

<!-- Click button to add new menu -->
<button class = "btn-add-menu-item">Add menu</button>



<!-- Below HTML where each `<li>` element is sortable and dropable -->


<ul class = "main-menu menu-group">
<!-- cloned <li> elements are appendTo to this <ul> but nothing can be dropped on the cloned element -->
 
 <li>
 
  <div> Main Menu 1 </div>
  
  <ul class = "sub-menu-1 menu-group">
   <li>
    <div> Submenu 1 </div>
    
    <ul class = "sub-menu-2 menu-group">
     <!-- Here is empty but dropable to receive <li> elements -->
    </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </li>
 
 
 <li>
 
  <div> Main Menu 2 </div>
 
  <ul class = "sub-menu-1 menu-group">
   <li>
    <div> Submenu 2 </div>
    
    <ul class = "sub-menu-2 menu-group">
     <!-- Here is empty but dropable to receive <li> elements -->
    </ul>
   </li>
  
  </ul>
  
  
 </li>


</ul>
```

What am I missing so that other dropable or sortable elements can be dropped on my cloned elements. I have tried several solutions on SO but I have not go solution.

Comment: It will be easy to help you if you can create  a demo of the problem you are facing, using stack snippets or a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Manish I have added the working snippet now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding sortable class doesn't make it sortable, you need to call `.sortable()` on it after cloning. Something like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".main-menu, .sub-menu-1, .sub-menu-2").sortable({  

    connectWith: '.menu-group',
    placeholder: 'drop-placeholder'

  }).disableSelection();



//The problem occurs regarding the HTML below. I clone the `<li>` 
//element and I append it to a `<ul>` element where all `<li>` 
//elements are sortable and dropable. However I am unable to drop 
//any element on cloned elements.


  $('.btn-add-menu-item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $(".menu-checkbox").each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).next('ul').addClass('sub-menu-1 menu-group');
        $(this).parents('li').clone(true).appendTo('.main-menu').sortable({connectWith: '.menu-group',placeholder: 'drop-placeholder'}).find('.sub-menu-1, .sub-menu-2').sortable({connectWith: '.menu-group',placeholder: 'drop-placeholder'});
      }


    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.drop-placeholder{
   border: 1px dashed green;
}

.menu-group{
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




<!-- Below is the HTML of new menu items to clone -->
<!-- and add when the button is clicked -->


<ul class = "add-menu">
 <li> 
  <input type = "checkbox" class = "menu-checkbox">New Menu Item 1
  
  <ul class = "new-menu">
   <!-- Here is empty must be dropable to receive <li> elements -->
  </ul>
 
 </li>
 
 
 <li> 
  <input type = "checkbox" class = "menu-checkbox">New Menu Item 2
  
  <ul class = "new-menu">
   <!-- Here is empty must be dropable to receive <li> elements -->
  </ul>
 
 </li>



</ul>

<!-- Click button to add new menu -->
<button class = "btn-add-menu-item">Add menu</button>



<!-- Below HTML where each `<li>` element is sortable and dropable -->


<ul class = "main-menu menu-group">
<!-- cloned <li> elements are appendTo to this <ul> but nothing can be dropped on the cloned element -->
 
 <li>
 
  <div> Main Menu 1 </div>
  
  <ul class = "sub-menu-1 menu-group">
   <li>
    <div> Submenu 1 </div>
    
    <ul class = "sub-menu-2 menu-group">
     <!-- Here is empty but dropable to receive <li> elements -->
    </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </li>
 
 
 <li>
 
  <div> Main Menu 2 </div>
 
  <ul class = "sub-menu-1 menu-group">
   <li>
    <div> Submenu 2 </div>
    
    <ul class = "sub-menu-2 menu-group">
     <!-- Here is empty but dropable to receive <li> elements -->
    </ul>
   </li>
  
  </ul>
  
  
 </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: Flash, you have addressed my problem but I find this new issue regarding your solution: Once an element has been dropped on the cloned element, that element now fails to drop on any other element except the cloned element

Comment: Fixed, try now.